# Why is an $E_\infty$-operad a kind of ''strictification'' for a non-commutative operation?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

A topological space $X$ which is an [algebra](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/algebra+over+an+operad) over an [$E_\infty$-operad](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/E-infinity+operad) $E$ consists of a sequence of maps
$$
\mu_n':E(n)\times X^n\to X
$$
with compatibility conditions. The spaces $E(n)$ are contractible and the symmetric group $\Sigma_n$ acts freely on them.

If one would have a *strictly* associative operation $\mu:X\times X\to X$ then by iterating, one would get a map
$$
\mu_n:X^n\to X
$$
which factors, if $\mu$ is *strictly* commutative through $X^n/\Sigma_n$. Here, the group $\Sigma_n$ acts on $X^n$ by commuting the factors.

I guess, as suggested in the accepted answer to [this MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/6377/why-does-one-think-to-steenrod-squares-and-powers), that for an algebra $X$ over an $E_\infty$-operad $E$ (hence something ''weaker'' than a space with a strictly commutative operation), one gets a factorization of $\mu_n'$ through $(E(n)\times X^n)/\Sigma_n$.

> Why does one get such a factorization of $\mu_n'$? Is it ''obvious'' from the definition of an algebra over
>   an operad?

Comment: The definition of algebra over a _symmetric_ operad includes a compatibility condition on the action of the symmetric group. Is that what you are asking about?

Comment: Dear @ZhenLin, no that is not the problem. I was asking why there is such a factorization of $\mu_n'$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I confused two different kinds of $\Sigma_n$-invariance in my (now deleted) comment. In fact the factorisation you want is indeed just the compatibility condition for algebras over the symmetric operad. Indeed, given any symmetric operad $E$, the definition of $E$-algebra includes the condition
$$\sigma (e) \cdot (x_{\sigma (1)}, \ldots, x_{\sigma (n)}) = e \cdot (x_1, \ldots, x_n)$$
for all $\sigma$ in $\Sigma_n$. (The $\Sigma_n$-actions on $E (n)$ and $X^n$ are both *right* actions, despite the notation.) This is precisely the statement that the structure map $E (n) \times X^n \to X$ is $\Sigma_n$-invariant, which implies that it factors through the coinvariants.

Comment: Dear @ZhenLin, thank you for the answer. Please let me ask a little follow-up question raised by your comment. $X$ is called an $E_\infty$-algebra (http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/E-infinity+algebra) if it is an algebra over *some* $E_\infty$-operad $E$. Suppose I have another $E_\infty$-operad $E'$, is $X$ an algebra over $E'$ as well?

Comment: If you have an operad morphism $E' \to E$, then yes. I suppose if $E$ is fibrant as an operad then it would follow from the fact that all $E_\infty$-operads are weakly equivalent.